# How to override ftplugin set commands in Neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, autocmd, neovim-qt

One thing I hate about a lot of the default Vim plugins is that they add `o` to `formatoptions`. In Vim I would get around this by using `au FileType * set formatoptions-=o` in my vimrc, but for some reason this no longer works when using Neovim. How can I go about achieving this?

Details: Using Neovim 0.4.3 on neovim-qt

Comment: And does it work in vim for the same filetypes?

Comment: You can use `after` directory to overwrite plugin defaults. It wouldn't be that simple -- you will have to care about every plugin in question, but should work.

Comment: Try using a `BufWinEnter` event instead. That's a late event which should happen after all the filetype detection and setup is done. `au BufWinEnter * set fo-=o`.

Comment: sounds like a bug/regression to me

Comment: @filbranden thanks! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad this helped @Mason! Posted as an answer with a longer explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `BufWinEnter` event instead.

That's a late event, which should happen after all the filetype detection and setup is finished.

```
au BufWinEnter * set formatoptions-=o
```

The docs in [`:help BufRead`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html?#BufRead) suggest possibly using this event:

> See [`BufWinEnter`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html?#BufWinEnter) for when you need to do something after processing the modelines.

While your case is not directly about modelines, that was a hint that this event might be useful...

Please note this event may be triggered more than once for a specific buffer. If the command you're running is idempotent (which is the case with your command), that should be fine.